# Inconsistency between ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 Date range when comparing a DateTime

Tags: ruby

Ruby 1.8.7:

```
> r = (Date.civil(2010, 12, 1)..Date.civil(2010, 12, 31))
> r.include? DateTime.civil(2010,12,28,15,0)
=> true
```

Ruby 1.9.2

```
> r = (Date.civil(2010, 12, 1)..Date.civil(2010, 12, 31))
> r.include? DateTime.civil(2010,12,28,15,0)
=> false
```

Anyone knows why is that?, I so much prefer 1.8.7 behaviour, this inconsistency broke some of my code :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Range` objects in Ruby 1.9 act differently. Previously, `Range#include?` really just did a greater-than/less-than comparison. Now, however, it iterates over each item in the range (in this case, dates), and compares your value to each one.

Ruby 1.9 has added `Range#cover?`, which acts like the 1.8 version of `Range#include?` -- however, it is not backwards compatible with Ruby 1.8.

```
> r.cover? DateTime.civil(2010,12,28,15,0)
=> true
```

More info: http://rhnh.net/2009/08/03/range-include-in-ruby-1-9